# Java JComboBox Updating ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, items, updating

I have 3 `JComboBoxes` each with an `actionListener`. Upon selecting an item from any one of the `JComboBoxes` should update the content of the other two, and when two of the `JComboBoxes` are selected, the 3 combo box value should be updated based on the values selected from the other two `JComboBoxes`. I am updating the content using `setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(array))`
Am I suppose to use and actionlistener or an itemchangelistenner for the combo boxes? Is there a preference on the choice?

Comment: Without any code it would be pure guessing.

Comment: Yep, you've got a bug, but we haven't the ability to read minds yet to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1):

you can start with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539001/jcombobox-action-listener/6540003#6540003)