# Possible design patterns for JComboBoxes with multiple courses

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, jcombobox

I have a series of JComboBox and each value selected will change the flow of control and dynamically populate the following JComboBox.  Does anyone know of any design patterns that may match this criteria?  The course may look something like this...

```
Course 1    A1    A11    A111
                         A112
                         A113

                  A12    A121
                         A122

            A2    A21    A211
Course 2    ...   ...    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- put those Items to the one of [arrays type implemented in JComboBox API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox%28javax.swing.ComboBoxModel%29)
- put those arrays to the `Tree`, `util.List` or `HashMap` (depends of tree depth) with logics for gradual changes in linked rest of `JComboBox(es)`
- add [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html), [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to all [JComboBoxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540003/714968)